# Do I need a firewall and or Virus protection software

Tags: ubuntu, firewall

Having build my Ubuntu Pc and loaded TOR, it is now running very nicely as a Node.
This is within my home network.
The Node has got an IP static address, so it won't fail to get back as a Node if I have for any reason to shut it down.
I intend to have the power supply via APC, so if I get a power outage the Tor server will not be affected.
Like wise the ISP Hub so its always on the NET.
I do have virus protection AVG on my main PC with the Firewall attachments.
I will not be using the TOR relay for anything else , no email, no IRC etc.
The question - Does my TOR Relay need a separate firewall and or Virus protection.
If so what is recommended please.

Thank you for this,when your trying to understand a new system without anyone to talk to. I will keep persevering.

Have followed your instructions and find that ufw is already installed and running.

I then ran the  'sudo apt install unattended-upgrades'
it told me that the unattended-upgrades is already the newest version and that i could use the  'sudo apt autoremove' to remove some items that are no longer required.
all done and uptodate , thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu comes with a firewall, called [`ufw` (Uncomplicated Firewall)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) which should suffice, it is a front end to the Linux `iptables` packet filter.

To enable it:

```
sudo ufw allow 9001/tcp #change 9001 to your chosen ORPort
sudo ufw allow 22/tcp #if you remotely administrate with ssh
sudo ufw enable
```

You may need to add additional lines if there are other services that it's running that need to be accessible from the network.

I'd recommend *against* using any "antivirus" because it's mostly snakeoil and the offerings for Linux aren't very good and are more likely to be a vulnerability than an improvement in security.

A much more useful step to take is to enable are automatic updates:

```
sudo apt install unattended-upgrades
```

This will provide more protection than antivirus.

Comment: I'd be careful when using antivirus software. You'll add an additional attack vector, see [here](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/01/antivirus-is-bad/) and [here](https://www.syscan360.org/slides/2014_EN_BreakingAVSoftware_JoxeanKoret.pdf).